# jQuery to change all descendant DOM IDs according to a formula

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am cloning a DOM element with jQuery, a `div` with many descendants. Before inserting the cloned `div` into the DOM, I need to change the `id` attribute of those descendants that have one. I can do this for elements I know the `id` of already as follows (assuming `newElem` is my cloned element in the pre-insertion phase):

```
newElem.find('#question_0_0').attr('id', 'question_' + num1 + '_' + num2);
```

My problem is that one section of the `div` being cloned is generated programmatically. There are many (dozens) of divs in this section. I need to modify the numbers at the end of the generated `id`s in my cloned `div` before DOM insertion, but I don't know what the *beginning* of each id will be until the page is loaded.

How can I write something that effectively catches all elements with `id`s ending in `_0_0` (the first part of the div is unknown) and changes those `id`s to ~whatever~_+num1_num2? I know I can use wildcards to catch all of the elements that end with `_0_0`, but I don't know how to reuse that "captured" wildcard part in the rewriting of the ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[id$=_0_0]').prop('id', function(){
    var x = $(this).prop('id').split('_')[0]; //part before _0_0
    return x +'_'+ num1 + '_' + num2;
});
```

Comment: `prop` method accept 2 parameters, index and the oldProperty, there is no need to create a jQuery object here, +1 for using `prop` method.

Comment: This worked great -- thanks. After implementing, I realized that some of the ids that needed to be modified included some stuff after the `_0_0` string so I modified as follows:
`newElem.find('[id*=_0_0]').prop('id', function(){
    var x = $(this).prop('id').split('_0_0',2);
    return x[0] +'_'+ num1 + '_' + num2 + x[1];
});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id$="_0_0"]').prop('id', function(index, currentID) {
    return 'question_' + num1 + '_' + index;
})
```